# Command to edit files listed submitted changelist?

Tags: perforce

Is there a command to open for edit all files found in a previously submitted changelist at their latest version?

I don't want to rollback a changelist; I'm looking for a shortcut to open all the files for edit instead of resorting to finding all of the files and opening them one by one.

The best I can do is format the output of `p4 describe` and pipe it into `p4 edit`.

Comment: I don't think anything like that exists, but it sounds like you've got a good workaround...

Answer (score 1):

There is an example of this on the perforce public depot...
http://public.perforce.com/wiki/Perforce_Command_Line_Recipes

Look for    Open all the files in a submitted changelist for edit

There are a few flavours of this on that page, but the basic shell command is

```
p4 files ...@<change num>,<change num> | sed s/\#.*// | p4 -x - edit
```

Disclaimer: I've not actually tried this